# MapBox - Style Specifications - iOS - number-format

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

We needed to display the numbers on our map based on a chosen locale. I found the "number-format" style specifications on the Mapbox documentation. Since I can't seem to find a custom function for number formatting, the approach was to use MGL_FUNCTION using "number-format". So I've been on this problem for more than a day now.

Here are the once I have tried

```
let locale: [String: Any] = ["locale": "en", "min-fraction-digits": 1, "max-fraction-digits": 1]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: locale, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
```

// Use json string

```
let formattedNumber = NSExpression(format: "MGL_FUNCTION('number-format', CAST(value, 'NSNumber'), %@)", jsonString)
```

// Use dictionary

```
let formattedNumber = NSExpression(format: "MGL_FUNCTION('number-format', CAST(value, 'NSNumber'), %@)", locale)
```

// Use style specs "object" json string

```
let object = NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["object", jsonString])
let formattedNumber = NSExpression(format: "MGL_FUNCTION('number-format', CAST(value, 'NSNumber'), %@)", object)
```

// Use style specs "object" dictionary

```
let object = NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["object", locale])
let formattedNumber = NSExpression(format: "MGL_FUNCTION('number-format', CAST(value, 'NSNumber'), %@)", object)
```

All of which returns *'Invalid property value: [1][2]: Number-format options argument must be an object.'*

Hope anyone would be able to point out what I am doing wrong and the correct syntax/object format to pass for the "number-format" style specifications.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `NumberFormatter `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number-format` support was added to the cross-platform style parsing code [in 2019](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/14840), which means this expression operator would work when used inside a style JSON file bundled with the application or hosted on mapbox.com. However, `number-format` doesn’t seem to have ever been added to the iOS/macOS map SDK’s NSExpression conversion code. In the runtime styling API on iOS/macOS before v10.0.0, expressions are always round-tripped through NSExpression, even when you use `+[NSExpression expressionWithMGLJSONObject:]`.

In general, unrecognized operators should work when you use either `+[NSExpression expressionWithMGLJSONObject:]` or `MGL_FUNCTION` in an NSExpression format string. However, the NSExpression conversion code wraps any unrecognized JSON object in a `literal` expression, which would be invalid for `number-format`. There would need to be a special case similar to the one for `collator` expressions [when converting to NSExpression](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/blob/ddf8e35970d1a8a46171bd798bcfa8f22d2760e0/platform/darwin/src/NSExpression%2BMGLAdditions.mm#L731-L733) and [when converting to JSON](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/blob/ddf8e35970d1a8a46171bd798bcfa8f22d2760e0/platform/darwin/src/NSExpression%2BMGLAdditions.mm#L1244-L1248).

A more elegant fix would also include support for embedding an NSNumberFormatter into an NSExpression, but it would be more involved to convert between NSNumberFormatter options and the options accepted by the `number-format` operator in the style specification.

The immediate fix to enable `MGL_FUNCTION(@"number-format", …)` would be pretty small. You could open an issue in the [mapbox-gl-native-ios](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/) repository about it, though Mapbox’s priority these days is on the rewrite in [mapbox-maps-ios](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/) that will be released as v10. In v10, the runtime styling API has been overhauled to align more closely to the style specification; it doesn’t use NSExpression at all.